# sklearn's TfidfVectorizer word frequency?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a question about sklearn's TfidfVectorizer when it's doing the frequency of the word in each documents.

the sample code I saw is:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

>>> corpus = [

>>>     'The dog ate a sandwich and I ate a sandwich',
>>>     'The wizard transfigured a sandwich'
>>> ]

>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

>>> print vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()

[[ 0.75458397  0.37729199  0.53689271  0.          0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.44943642  0.6316672   0.6316672 ]]
```

my question is: how do I interpret the numbers in the matrix? I understand the 0 means that the word i.e. wizard appears 0 times in the first document therefore it's 0, but how do I interpret the number 0.75458397? Is it the frequency that the word "ate" appeared in the first document? Or the frequency of the word "ate" that occurs in the entire corpus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TF-IDF (which means "term frequency - inverse document frequency"), is *not* giving you the frequency of a term in its representation.

TF-IDF gives high scores to terms occurring in only very few documents, and low scores for terms occurring in many documents, so its roughly speaking a measure of how discriminative a term is in a given document. Take a look at [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tf-idf-weighting-1.html) resource to find an excellent description of TF-IDF and to get a better idea of what it is doing.

If you only want counts, you'd need to use `CountVectorizer`.

Comment: examine_row=tv_df.iloc[0] print(examine_row.sort_values(ascending=False))  The higher the number the more frequent its usage in the document

Comment: How does one get term frequencies alone? CountVectorizer returns counts, not frequencies...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by frequency? I.e. frequency as in "term frequency" means "counts".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're forgetting that TF-IDF vectors are usually normalized so they always have a magnitude (length or 2-norm) of 1.

So the TFIDF value `0.75` is the frequency of "ate" multiplied by the inverse document frequency of "ate" then **divided by the magnitude** of that TF-IDF vector.

Here are all the dirty details (skip to `tfidf0 =` for the punchline):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ["The dog ate a sandwich and I ate a sandwich",
          "The wizard transfigured a sandwich"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tfidfs = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)


from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

columns = [k for (v, k) in sorted((v, k)
           for k, v in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items())]
tfidfs = pd.DataFrame(tfidfs.todense(),
                      columns=columns)
#     ate   dog  sandwich  transfigured  wizard 
#0   0.75  0.38      0.54          0.00    0.00
#1   0.00  0.00      0.45          0.63    0.63

df = (1 / pd.DataFrame([vectorizer.idf_], columns=columns))
#     ate   dog  sandwich  transfigured  wizard
#0   0.71  0.71       1.0          0.71    0.71
corp = [txt.lower().split() for txt in corpus]
corp = [[w for w in d if w in vectorizer.vocabulary_] for d in corp]
tfs = pd.DataFrame([Counter(d) for d in corp]).fillna(0).astype(int)
#    ate  dog  sandwich  transfigured  wizard
#0    2    1         2             0       0
#1    0    0         1             1       1

# The first document's TFIDF vector:
tfidf0 = tfs.iloc[0] * (1. / df)
tfidf0 = tfidf0 / pd.np.linalg.norm(tfidf0)
#        ate       dog  sandwich  transfigured  wizard
#0  0.754584  0.377292  0.536893           0.0     0.0

tfidf1 = tfs.iloc[1] * (1. / df)
tfidf1 = tfidf1 / pd.np.linalg.norm(tfidf1)
#    ate  dog  sandwich  transfigured    wizard
#0   0.0  0.0  0.449436      0.631667  0.631667
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Print below code you will see output some thing like that

```
#(0, 1)        0.448320873199    Document 1, term = Dog
#(0, 3)        0.630099344518    Document 1, term = Sandwitch

    print(vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus))  
# if python 3 other wise remove () in print
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE : Use this if you have only unigrams**

sklearn's tfidfvectorizer won't directly give you count.
To get count you can use `TfidfVectorizer` class method `inverse_transform` and `build_tokenizer`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = [
    'The dog ate a sandwich and I ate a sandwich',
    'The wizard transfigured a sandwich'
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
X_words = tfidf.inverse_transform(X) ## this will give you words instead of tfidf where tfidf > 0

tokenizer = vectorizer.build_tokenizer() ## return tokenizer function used in tfidfvectorizer

for idx,words in enumerate(X_words):
    for word in words:
        count = tokenizer(corpus[idx]).count(word)
        print(idx,word,count)
```

Output

```
0 dog 1
0 ate 2
0 sandwich 2
1 sandwich 1
1 wizard 1
1 transfigured 1
#0 means first sentence in corpus
```

This is a work around hope might help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

it should be `vectorizer` in the line 
`X_words = tfidf.inverse_transform(X)`
instead of tfidf.